# Simple JS minifier on php

Tags: php, javascript, minify

I want to minify and possibly compress JavaScript while running a website in dev mode.

The most popular solutions seem to be too comprehensive (Assetic, minify) or based on tools I don't have access to (Assetic: symfony, Uglify.js: nodeJS).

I would like to:

- Manually pass in paths of several js files
- Get one compressed, minified js file back that can be written to the filesystem

How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean "too comprehensive"? i'd think a tool like minify is exactly what you're looking for

Comment: [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) does *exactly* what you want.  I don't think it's "too comprehensive" at all (whatever that means).

Comment: I have trouble understanding how minify is set up properly. Is there a beginner tutorial (more detailed than https://code.google.com/p/minify/wiki/UserGuide)?

Comment: @Urs: The README file should help: https://github.com/mrclay/minify/blob/master/README.txt

Comment: @RocketHazmat I got it to work, thanks! What I understood now is I can configure all the scripts in groupsConfig.php and then call the minified, combined file via <script src="/min/g=js"></script>. But: what I originally wanted to do was: minify only in dev mode and write the file to disk, then use that file. Wouldn't that be more performant - or is it better to trust minify that it handles caching, gzipping and headers on its own?

Comment: @Urs: Pretty minify takes care of that for you.  If you want, you can "save as" the generated file and use that :)

Comment: You mean "save as" as in "save manually"? I am looking for an automatical solution I can integrate into a CMS extension for a permanent workflow. Well, I'll look into that. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use yuicompressor.jar? Correct compression of the code with high ratio is non-trivial task and it's already done in yuicompressor.

Comment: `.jar` doesn't sound like PHP :-)